# export data from set of tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, spool, oracle19c

I have a usecase where in set of stored procedures are getting called ( using scheduler ) which consists of below operation pattern -

1. Set some variables like current application date etc. [ Done]
2. Execute queries on DB tables to populate Global Temporary tables as per usercases [ Done ]
3. Export these result as per report case ( using where clause on temp tables) in CSV file format **[ Need Help ]**
4. CSV file directory is based on report type and name of the csv file is dynamic based on day/time. **[Need Help]**

These stored procedures are suppose to schedule and run daily to generates reports in timely manner. 
Now, we are not able to perform how we can export these resultset which is present in temporary tables.

I tried SPOOL functionality but looks like it is SQLPLUS based and not sure if we can use it in Stored procedure, Is there ANYWAY we can use it in this flow in stored procedure. If not - what are the possible options to invoke SPOOL in Oracle 19c ? If so - Temporary table data will be available as we understood that it is at session level only. Please let us know if you have any workaround for same.

```
set term off
set feed off
set feedback off
set sqlformat csv
spool 'D:\test\outputExample.csv'
select Date_Time,a,b,c,Net_Amount from temp_tbl1 ;
spool off
```

As data volume for each csv report is on higher side , i am avoiding using **utl_file** functionality. 
Are there any features available in Oracle 19c for same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SPOOL` is a `SQL Plus` feature, you cannot use it inside PL/SQL. Many tools like SQL Developer etc. support sqlplus commands. Having said that, you need to call all the procedures and invoke sqlplus as OS level. If you want to write the output from a procedure to a OS file, then you could use `UTL_FILE`. If you want to avoid this, then the only way is to use `DBMS_OUTPUT` inside your procedures and then spool the output to a file.

From Oracle `12.2` onward, you could use **SET MARKUP** command:

```
SET MARKUP CSV ON
```

The `SET MARKUP` syntax has two options:

- **CSV**
- **HTML**

The `CSV` option has the following syntax:

```
CSV {ON|OFF} [DELIMI[TER] character] [QUOTE {ON|OFF}]
```

See the [SQLPlus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/generating-HTML-reports-from-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-1743F2F2-EBF3-48F7-9620-4F72B8988335) for creating [CSV reports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-0AA910C4-C22A-4A9E-BE13-AAA059CC7919).

Alternate solution to `UTL_FILE`:

You could use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to create a job to the SQL script. In recent versions, the database scheduler has been enhanced to be able to to run SQL Plus style scripts directly out of the database without needing to give OS access to database server, or the SQL*Plus executable.

For example:

```
declare
  sql_script   VARCHAR2(32767) :=
  'conn /@db
  set markup csv on
  set pages 0
  set lines 200
  set trimspool on
  spool c:\your_directory\file.csv
  select * from tab;
  spool off';
begin
 dbms_scheduler.create_job(
   job_name        => 'UNLOAD_DATA',
   job_type        => 'SQL_SCRIPT',
   job_action      => sql_script,
   credential_name => 'username',
   enabled         => true
   );
end;
/
```

You could expand and implement the above example to your complex procedures. There is a good explanation [here](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2018/06/20/the-death-of-utl_file/).

Comment: If you read the question in detail - Query is around - invoking spool export feature in stored procedure which are populating support Temp tables .i have tried spool from sqlplus utility and it works well. Fyi.  Thanks.

Comment: `spool` is a sqlplus command and not a `PL/SQL` command. For reporting etc. sqlplus could be easily used in silent mode at OS level. Now ponder about this, is it a good idea to invoke a OS process inside a procedure? You need to step back and go back to the drawing board and think about the design than jumping on "how" to achieve the result. Focus on, "what" to do.

Comment: Completely agree. I think - spool might not work in this case as data is getting aggregated and generated in temp tables in stored procs which are getting executed on daily schedulers. Any other alternatives ?

Comment: @Vicky There is indeed a way using scheduler. I have updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: It just solves one part of it i.e. invoking spool, problem statement is - Invoking export of temp table which are part of stored procedure, i dont see option to do it. Temp table data is also available at given session only so we need to perform extract of data within same session. let me know if you have any suggestion on same.

Comment: If you are using global temporary tables and looking to export data from that session to an OS file then it's a design disaster. There is a very ugly way to achieve whay you are looking for, use `client_info` to output the data for the session. The output from the session will be available in `v$session`.

Comment: Would it be possible to call a job which was created ( you suggested above from Stored procedure using run_job or anything similar )  ? if you have sample , that would be helpful.

Comment: You can see the examples here https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/scheduler-enhancements-12cr2